# Sequential Keras model output not matching label input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a sequential model in Keras that will take an input feature of `shape(1, n, 5)` and an input label of `shape(1, 1)` and return an output of `shape(1, 1)` to match the input label.

I built a model from a tutorial that works well with features `shape(n, 5)` and labels `shape(n, 1)` and returns an output of `shape(n, 1)`, which matches the input label.

Here is the model

```
class Model(keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, units):
        super().__init__()
        self.dense1 = keras.layers.Dense(
            units=units,
            activation=tf.nn.relu,
            kernel_initializer=tf.random.normal,
            bias_initializer=tf.random.normal,
        )
        self.dense2 = keras.layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, x2, training=True, mask=None):
        x1 = self.dense1(x2)
        x1 = self.dense2(x1)
        tf.squeeze(x1, axis=-1)
        return x1
```

Here is how I call it

```
            model.fit(
                features, labels,
                epochs=100,
                verbose=1,
            )
```

When I give the model features of `shape(1, n, 5)` and labels of `shape(1, 1)`, it returns `shape(1, n, 5)`. Does this mean all n feature sets were checked against the one label? I want the model to treat the `shape(n, 5)` as a single input.

To do that, I tried this

```
self.dense1 = keras.layers.Dense(
            input_shape=[None, 5],
            units=units,
            activation=tf.nn.relu,
            kernel_initializer=tf.random.normal,
            bias_initializer=tf.random.normal,
        )
```

but that did not do anything to the output shape.

How do I get the model to treat the `shape(n, 5)` as a single input?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up feeding the model features of `shape(1, 5*n)` by transforming the features into another shape. This ends up concatenating the feature set of 5 values n times in order, so I assume that is the best way to approach this particular problem.

```
        features = tf.reshape(features, [-1])
        features = tf.expand_dims(features, 0)
```